# Auto connect to erlang cluster

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing, distributed

I have an erlang application which I will need to run in distributed way.

Now to form a cluster, erlang nodes need to share the same cookie value and to get connected either of the below approach could be taken -

> net_adm:ping/1
>
> net_kernel:connect_node/1

but doing this way I will need to maintain the node list and also handle the failover in custom way. Even in case of failover how to know the which node to connect to, as the starting nodelist could have been changed till then.

So can anyone suggest how to form a erlang cluster with minimum effort and future nodes can join the cluster automatically without giving the actual nodeList.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many 100% fool-proof solutions for this. Many of us have implemented our own solutions every now and then. I did this, at least, 3 times in my life.

2 of them, I used an external database (Redis once, MySQL once) where I registered and unregistered current living nodes.

The other opportunity, I used `net_adm:world()` and `.erlang.hosts`. Take a look at [the docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html#world-0) for that.

I’m also aware of some projects working on a generalization of this kind of tool: I think Erlang Solutions was working in one, and I’m not sure if LASP or Partisan or something other tool by Chris Meiklejohn. You should check those out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

As you mentioned in your custom solution you maintained the node list in Redis/Mysql and register/de-register living nodes. On successful registration did you connect the current node using net_kernel:connect_node/1/net_adm:ping/1 with each node traversing all the registered living nodes or took any different approach.

Did you do any cleanup on de-registration also? Had you used net_kernel:monitor_nodes/1 for capturing node status change. Actually on unsubscribing I will need to update a Mnesia table.

Comment: On successful registration I just used `net_adm:ping` to one node… that's all it takes to connect to all of them.

Comment: No cleanup on deregistration, but… all nodes used `net_kernel:monitor_nodes(true, [nodedown_reason])` to detect when other nodes loose connection so they can be removed from the node list in the database.

Comment: Thanks. Understood, You said that on deregistration you just removed the node from the list , but on deregistration all the node subscribed to et_kernel:monitor_nodes(true, [nodedown_reason]) would receive the event and will try to delete the node from the nodeList. So how did you synchronize?
Also can you please tell me how did you ensure the high-availability and handle the failover of the cluster. Coz if any node goes down I will need to make it up and join the cluster.

Comment: Yeah, all the nodes receive the message and all of them try to remove it from the table. One succeeds, the others just issue some useless deletes. No big deal.

Comment: Of course that system was barely tolerant to network partitions. When one was detected (i.e. a node detected that it was removed from the list of nodes, IIRC)… an system-level alarm was triggered and manual intervention was required. Happily, we never actually needed that.

Comment: Same goes for high-availability. We didn’t have that requirement, we used an elastic load balancer and just booted up new nodes when the system performance dropped significantly.